# How to call coffee script function from controller in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Could you please guide me on how to call a coffee function such as update table in an example below from a coffee script

```
updateTable = (data) ->
  $('#employee-table tbody').append """
    <tr>
      <td>#{data.name}</td>
      <td>#{data.position}</td>
      <td>#{data.office}</td>
      <td>#{data.extension}</td>
      <td>#{data.start_date}</td>
      <td><a href="/employees/#{data.id}">Show</a></td>
      <td><a href="/employees/#{data.id}/edit">Edit</a></td>
      <td><a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/employees/#{data.id}">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
  """
  return

$ ->
  $('#add_employee').on 'ajax:success', (data) ->
    $('#add_employee')[0].reset()
    return
  pusher = new Pusher('<%= ENV["PUSHER_KEY"] %>',
    cluster: '<%= ENV["PUSHER_CLUSTER"] %>'
    encrypted: true)
  channel = pusher.subscribe('employee')
  channel.bind 'new', (data) ->
    updateTable data
    return
  return
```

Comment: Can you try putting this in your controller action ? `format.js { render :js => "updateTable();" }`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna how to passing an argument data?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript), it's much more cleaner